# Where did Han and Chewie take a shower in Solo?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In the movie *Solo: A Star Wars Story*

> after the escape from Mimban in the AT-Hauler

Han and Chewie take a shower. Now I've only seen the movie a couple of times, but from memory this scene happens.

> not long *after* they escape Mimban but *before* they arrive on Vandor to steal the coaxium from the conveyex.

If so, this would imply that they take a shower while still on the AT-Hauler, which seems a little odd.

Where did the shower scene take place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course, they take shower on AT-Hauler while flying to Vandor. This ship has facility to take shower along with others such as carrying heavy cargo.

Since their next target was Vandor, and they didn't land anywhere during their journey from Mimban to Vandor, it is obvious that they took shower on the ship.

You can see in above video that that ship is flying to Vandor and in the next shot, Han starts taking shower which is interrupted by Chewbacca.

Comment: Has any book showing a cross-section of the Hauler been published yet? It would be interesting to see whereabouts on the ship the shower is.

Comment: @StevenRands No, not yet. Even the [databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/at-hauler) gives a short description. [Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Y-45_armored_transport_hauler) seems to mention a shower stall but it is not official.

Comment: Fun fact: Wookies are renowned for their mechanical skills partially due to their lifelong training cleaning out their shower drains.